# He asks weird questions : Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, word

Grandpa likes to make weird statements and ask weird questions. Only the other day he asked:

> "Make a Long Table Out of a Wall"
>
> "What am I doing? Need a one word answer"

He does have a way with his English.

**Hint**:

> Capitalization means something.

Comment: Should I be guessing what the one word answer is?

Comment: Yes. I am sorry if I confused you

Comment: No problem - it's an alluring puzzle and just wanted to make sure I was thinking the right way :)

Comment: Hint : Capitalization means something!

Comment: Looks like "ML TO WIN" but there's an extra "w".

Comment: Going from left to right, top to bottom, caps are "MWL IT NOW", but a hint would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint says that capitalisation is important. If we interpret each capitalised word to mean

> the start of a new sub-clue,

Grandpa's first sentence looks like this:

> Make a
>  Long
>  Table
>  Out of a
>  Wall

So maybe we need to find a word that fits in all of these somehow.

> [Make a **run** (for it)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_a_run_for_it)
>  [(in the) long **run**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_long_run)
>  [**run** (the) table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/run_the_table)
>  [**run** out of (something)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/run_out)
>  [wall **run**](https://parkour.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_Run)

So maybe Grandpa is

> **running**?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe grandpa is

> programming?

All the capitalized words

> have something to do with programming. "Make" is a compiling tool, "long" is a datatype, "table" is a data structure, "out" is either a parameter type or short for output, and "Wall" is a compiler flag signifying "show all warnings".

Answer (score 0):

Is grandpa perhaps:

> Malting? - Based on *MALT*. The hint says that capitalization means something, well I couldn't come up with much on an acrostic, nor could I piece the letters together very well. *Malt* is the combination of the first letter from the first four words; technically giving *MaLT*.

I know it's probably wrong, but a guess is worth a shot at this point. Great puzzle by the way!

Comment: @Candleshank those capitalized words all tied to rot13 (Eha). Make a ___  , Long ___