# Word that is fun. Nine and one

Tags: word, no-computers

> Starts with a name, ends with a name
>
> Starts with a charge, ends with a charge
>
> Starts with an element, ends with an element

Would be fun to guess this one! (May be more than one?)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A long shot - it may be a

> Billion - it is 1 with nine zeroes and may be fun to be $1,000,000,000 in credit.

Starts with a name, ends with a name

> Bill and say Lion

Starts with a charge, ends with a charge

> Charge - bill, charge - ion

Starts with an element, ends with an element

> B- boron / Bi - bismuth, N - nitrogen

Comment: Surprised it took you that long @Tom. Incredible.

Comment: @DEEM - I really want to know "Make a Long Table Out of a Wall" from [Grandpa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68978/he-asks-weird-questions-another-grandpa-mystery).

Comment: Make a ___   In the Long ____     ____ the Table  ___ out of a Wall

Comment: A tidbit. Found out that Billion meant " million million" in UK for a while. Long case.

Comment: Yep, when I was at school in late 70s that was still the original meaning, but even then the US $1000 million amount was popular, and now it's taken over.

Comment: znxr n eha... va gur ybat eha... eha gur gnoyr... hmm...

Answer (score 13):

I guess this depends on your idea of fun, but I got

> politician

because it starts with

> the name Pol ([as in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol_Pot)), the charge P ([as in](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142150)), and the element P ([as in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus))

and ends with

> the name Ian ([as in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_MacArthur)), the charge N ([as in](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142150)) and the element N ([as in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen)).

Like I said, it might fulfil some people's definition of a good time, but it definitely

> has **9+1**=10 letters.

Answer (score 6):

Is it:

> ACED?

Starts with a name, ends with a name

> *ACE* is a name, as is *ED* (short for Edward)

Starts with a charge, ends with a charge

> I'm thinking electrical charge here -  *AC* is *alternating current*. I'm a bit unsure about the end, but *ED* stands for *Electricity Duty*, the amount of money you are *charged* for electricity (so a different kind of charge)

Starts with an element, ends with an element

> *AC* is the symbol for *Actinium* and *D* is *Deuterium*.

Comment: Nine and One????

Comment: Word that is fun?

Comment: Fun as in interesting

Comment: Suggestion for fun word: rot13(Npr sbe pneqf pna or jbegu bar be avar cyhf bar, naq cynlvat pneqf vf sha, rfcrpvnyyl trggvat na nprq unaq)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> comic? (funny or amusing, a comedian)

Nine and one:

> far-fetched...comic = comedian: Co (cobalt) - chemical element group 9, Na (sodium) - chemical element group 1

Starts with a name, ends with a name:

> com is a domain name and Mic is a name

Starts with a charge, ends with a charge:

> C is a symbol for Coulomb - the standard unit of electric charge

Starts with an element, ends with an element:

> C is also a symbol of carbon, an element

Answer (score 2):

This, is, without a doubt, *not the answer the OP is looking for*, but I think it works.

Technically this is two words, but:

> Disintegration beam!

Starts with a name, ends with a name:

> DIS is the stock ticker for Disney, which is named after the person who founded the company. I have to reach a bit for the name at the end, but the right half of M (the very, very end) is N, which is the name of a [Pokemon Trainer](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/N)

Starts with a charge, ends with a charge:

> [Discharge](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Discharge_(move)) and [Charge Beam](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charge_Beam_(move)) are both Pokemon moves.

Starts with an element, ends with an element:

> D is used as the abbreviation for [deuterium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium), an isotope of hydrogen, and Am is the abbreviation for [americium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americium).

Comment: It is one word I am looking for. Very common one too.