# An easy trillionth power

Tags: mathematics

Hardy was revisiting Ramanujan and this time arrived in taxicab number 1792. He remarked that this number seemed rather dull.

Ramanujan replied, "It is very interesting, it is the product of the first six digits of a trillionth power."

Please find a whole number such that, when raised to the power 1 000 000 000 000, its first six digits (from left to right) multiply to give 1792.

Comment: I think Ramanujan would've called that number "billion".

Comment: Even I would have once have called this number a [billion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77662/word-that-is-fun-nine-and-one/77668#comment227852_77668). It's safer for this question to have a higher power and a lakh crore should do.

Comment: This isn't a very interesting property. You can pick any sequence of 6 digits where the first digit isn't 0 and have those 6 digits be the first 6 digits of a trillionth power, so any product of 6 single-digit integers is the product of the first 6 digits of a trillionth power.

Comment: @Tom Is the accepted solution the intended solution?  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @Steven - the solution is as intended. I should say it's (adapted) from "Find a positive integer $n<10,000,000$ such that the first four digits (in the decimal expansion) of $n^{1,000,000}$ are all different" from [Richard Stanley's page](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/misc.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that the story as told above is true. I remember (not sure from where) that Ramanujan's answer was 'it is the smallest number expessible as the sum of two positive cubes in two ways'. Hardy then asked what the corresponding number for fourth powers would be, and Ramanujan answered after a short pause that he didn't know, but that it would be very large. See https://vedicmathschool.org/story-of-hardy-ramanujan-number-1729/

Comment: @Peter: The story is completely made up for the puzzle. Note how the number is 1792, not 1729. It's presented as a sequel to the story of the actual Hardy-Ramanujan number.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oops! Sorry!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First observe that the first $6$ digits of

> $e = \mathbf{2.71828}\ 18284 \ldots$

happen to multiply to $1792$. Now all we need is to remember the bounds

> $(1+\frac 1 n)^n < e < (1+\frac 1 n)^{n+1}$ (for positive $n$)

to find that the number

> $1\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 001$

does the trick.

Indeed, setting $n = 1\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000$ we get

> $e > 1.000\ 000\ 000\ 001^{1\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000} > \frac e {1.000\ 000\ 000\ 001}$.

Multiplying through with $1\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000^{1\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000}$ we confirm that the first $10$ or so digits of the $1\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000$th power and of

> $e$

are the same as desired.

Comment: OK, that is *clever*.

Comment: Indeed the first 12 digits are the same (the 13th differs).

Answer (score 5):

The smallest natural number that fits the bill is

> 1931

but

> that's 11 years after his death

so I guess the other answer is better...

Code to find that number, computing not the exact powers but only their first 100 digits but computing lower and upper bound and checking that their first six digits are the same so we know they're exact:

```
import math

i = 0
while True:
    b = B = i
    e = 10**12
    p = P = 1
    while e:
        if e % 2:
            p *= b
            P *= B
            while p > 10**100:
                p //= 10
                P = -(P // -10)
        e //= 2
        b *= b
        B *= B
        while b > 10**100:
            b //= 10
            B = -(B // -10)
    p = str(p)
    P = str(P)
    assert len(p) == len(P)
    assert p[:6] == P[:6]
    if math.prod(map(int, p[:6])) == 1792:
        print(i)
        break
    i += 1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVJLTsMwEJXY4VPMBskNhDpZ0FIpLHwCL9ghFrFwFYsmsRxXiLOw6QYOxWkYe0KLBViyNO-9-TyN_fbhXkM3DofD-z5sy_Xn2bnt3egD9G3oGLPQgGAvnd0ZuPd7s2GARyMr8dqEDEaVKIqqTtAhVJFKiErnunjsFgsuoD4xVFQ0oDNKRUpmFDVzcEfzhMibUKPlMtr5JURLJVcoQ1mJxVE3qaA-Yp07kbkLcqD_c6D_mi7TZJlNjkuagueOoJqhIthOk8En2JkBE6BpUpRr7mFz8xglFQM2bzY-2rXz4xPvW8ftEK4ocZG6VKvbH2t3HnVuT5vQ3rTP1AkuMZt-xPwxvj_IFw)